# AWS API Gateway Developer Portal breaks in invite mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, openapi, aws-api-gateway

I have problem with API Gateway Developer portal I can't understand and make a rollback to previous state.

1. I had a Developer portal up an running right.
2. I Disable its self-registration with CLI
   `aws cognito-idp update-user-pool --user-pool-id $idPoolId --admin-create-user-config '{\"AllowAdminCreateUserOnly\": true}'`
3. As a developer portal admin I send first invitation to a new user
4. New user can sign-in with account and password provided in email, but published API list is empty ("No APIs published") and she hasn't Dasboard-link
5. At same time admins Admin panel accounts -> Invites page is totally empty
6. In Cognito I can see that a new invited user is not in Developer Portals register Users -group
7. If in Cognito Console this new user is added to Registered users group she can see Published APIs in list but cannot subscribe

Returning to state where Cognitos self-servive sign-up is enabled again doesn't help. New (with sign-up function) registered account doesn't go to the registered users -Group.

I have multiple environments in different regions and this is situation in all of them we have tried to use invite-only registration.

At first I need to know how to rollback to state where self-service sign-up works and promotes a new user to  Registered user-group. After that we need to find way to switch to invite-only mode user registrations.

All of this fuss is because Developer Portal haven't as a default function proper pending/verifying process for a new accounts.

Comment: Have you deployed your API Gateway so it is running the version you expect?  Just confirming since that could be a piece of the puzzle.